# Prevent macOS Ventura from create separate desktop space while in full-screen

Tags: macbook-pro, display, fullscreen

I am using base 14" MacBook Pro running macOS Ventura. It is hooked to j5create triple monitor docking station with two external display, passthrough power delivery and Logitech Unifying Receiver for keyboard and mouse.

Although everything is working fine, the way j5create implemented display drivers and Mac's limitations, I can only have one desktop space spanning over multiple displays (which is not the case when plugging monitors directly to mac). That is the reason when going in to fullscreen in one display make the rest of display go black. It won't let me change the desktop space in other monitor.

Is there a way to make apps go fullscreen without making it actual full, kinda like how iTerm 2 handles fullscreen?

Thanks.

Comment: "one desktop space spanning over multiple displays" Does the Displays control panel actually think the attached displays register as one display of 10,000 x 1080 [or approximately so]? Otherwise, it's in System prefs > Mission Control > Displays have separate spaces [pre Ventura equivalent, the placing may have changed]

Comment: @Tetsujin yes, it recognized 3 separate displays, but I turned off "Displays have separate spaces". I turned it on and it is not back to normal now. Thank you so much! Can you post this as an answer so that I can make it answered?

Comment: This has been asked many times - let me cross-link it to one of the others to make it easier to search in future.